# could not send email in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, webforms

```
<div id="id04" class="modal">
                <form class="modal-content" action="#">
                    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id04').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                    <div class="modalcontainer">
                        <p style="font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; font-size: 20px;">Reset Password</p>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_resetEmail" CssClass="inputtxt" PlaceHolder="Email Address" runat="server" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_resetPassword" CssClass="inputtxt" PlaceHolder="New Password" runat="server" TextMode="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_confirmNewPassword" CssClass="inputtxt" PlaceHolder="Confirm Password" runat="server" TextMode="password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CompareValidator
                            ID="CompareValidator2"
                            runat="server"
                            ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match."
                            ControlToValidate="txt_confirmNewPassword"
                            ControlToCompare="txt_resetPassword"
                            Operator="Equal" Type="String"
                            ForeColor="Red">
                        </asp:CompareValidator>

                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btnsignin" runat="server" Text="Confirm" OnClick="btnSignIn_Confirm"/>
                        //when the user clicks on this button, email is being sent

                    </div>

                    <div class="register">
                        Don't have an account? 
                        <a onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none';document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block';">Create an Account
                        </a>
                        <br />
                        <a style="color: #EC7063; font-size: 12px;"
                            onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none';document.getElementById('id03').style.display='block';">Sign in as Admin</a>
                    </div>

                    

                </form>
            </div>
```

//backend code in the MasterPage.master.cs

```
protected void btnSignIn_Confirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("come in");

        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add("to email");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("from email", "head", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.Subject = "This mail is send from asp.net application";
        mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.Body = "This is Email Body Text";
        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from email", "password");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Can send email");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("soemthing wrong");
        }
    }
```

the system.Diagnostic.Writeline("") is also not writing anything on my output so I have no idea where my code is going

when I click on the button, my webpage just refreshes and nothing is being shown, I have created a real email for the "mail.from" in my code, and use my personal email as the "mail.ToAdd". But I did not receive anything

Comment: Do you have multi-factor authentication on your Google account? Then see if you can create an app-password for use here

Comment: create a file log to check for exceptions - probably you try to read the wrong way the debug infos

Answer (score 0):

First try turn on less secure apps on for your google account to that fallow this [link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)
if not work's
try providing Host value in Constructor of SmptClient
insted of doing

```
  client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

do

```
  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
```

Comment: then go to this link https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps and toggle to on you might not enabled less secured apps then